# Reverse the given number program in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I was trying to execute this program but it only outputs the `~` symbol.

This is the code:

```
DECLARE
   N_NUM   NUMBER := 234;
   N_REM   NUMBER;
   N_REV   NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   WHILE N_NUM != 0
   LOOP
      N_REM := MOD (N_NUM, 10);
      N_NUM := (N_NUM / 10);
      N_REV := N_REV * 10 + N_REM;
   END LOOP;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (N_REV);
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A second option is using the `REVERSE()` function. 
However, that function would like to input a CHAR, not a NUMBER. 
So you will have to convert that first.

For example:

```
DECLARE
   N_Num NUMBER := 234;
   N_Rev NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   SELECT REVERSE(TO_CHAR(N_Num)) INTO N_Rev FROM Dual;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (N_Rev);
END;
/
```

Comment: Except that `REVERSE` is an undocumented feature, so be wary of using it in production code.

Comment: @Tenzin. The outcome will be a `char`. you need to again convert it to `num` after reversing. Is it ?

Comment: I declared `N_Rev` as a `NUMBER`.

Answer (score 2):

Before dividing by 10 you have to subtract the remainder. The following code will work.

```
DECLARE
   N_NUM   NUMBER := 234;
   N_REM   NUMBER;
   N_REV   NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   WHILE N_NUM <> 0
   LOOP
      N_REM := MOD (N_NUM, 10);
      N_NUM := ( (N_NUM - N_REM) / 10);
      N_REV := N_REV * 10 + N_REM;
   END LOOP;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (N_REV);
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Floor function as shown below:

```
N_NUM := FLOOR(N_NUM/10)
```

As this floor function returns only 23 instead of 23.4

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace function ReverseNo(no1 in number)
   return number
   Is 
        n number:=no1;
        p number;
        c number:=0;
begin
      while ( n>0)
      LOOP
        p:=mod(n,10);
        c:=c*10+p;
        n:=(n-p)/10;
      END LOOP; 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO IS ' || c);
     return c;
 end;
```